# Difference of returning a lambda function vs returning a method in python decorator

Tags: lambda, python-decorators

I am trying to understand the difference of returning a lambda vs a method in a decorator below. The calling object instance "o" is missing and not passed by the decorator when returning m.fm.  The decorator will pass the instance while returning a lambda function. Is it possible to pass the calling object by returning a method in decorator?

```
def deco(*type):
    def wrapper(func):
        m = M()
        # return lambda callingobj, *args: m.fm(callingobj, *args)
        return m.fm
    return wrapper

class M(object):
    def fm(self, callingobj, *args):
        print(f'self_ {callingobj}, args {args}')

class O(object):
    @deco('int')
    def fo(self, *args):
        print(f'{args}')


o = O()
o.fo(1, 2, 3)
```

Output:

1. with `return lambda callingobj, *args: m.fm(callingobj, *args)`

   `callingobj <__main__.O object at 0x000002453BE95760>, args (1, 2, 3)`
2. with `return m.fm`

   `callingobj 1, args (2, 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the lambda expression, the attribute `O.fo` is bound to a `function` object. When accessed, `o.fo` produces the value of `O.fo.__get__(o, O)`, which is a `method` object that passes its arguments on to the function. That is, `__get__` returns a function whose first parameter is `callingobj`, which gets bound to `o`. The remaining arguments are bound as a tuple `(1, 2, 3) to`args`

With `return m.fm`, the attribute `O.fo` is bound to the `method` object produced by `m.fm`, which is equivalent to `M.fm.__get__(m, M)`. Importantly, a `method` object has no `__get__` method, so `o.fo` gives you the method of the `M` class directly. *Now* the arguments `1`, `2`, and `3` are assigned such that 1 is assigned to `callingobj` and `(2, 3)` is assigned to `args`.

In other words, the difference is the order in which some function's `__get__` method relative to when the arguments to `o.fo` are processed.

Comment: @chepener. Instead of `return m.fm`. I tried using `return m.fm.__func__` and get the same result. `m.fm.__func__` does have `__get__`.   I actually tried to figure out if it is possible to use stack multimethod decorator from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483650/python-lost-self-while-decorating-class-multimethods). Using lambda breaks stack of multiple multimethod decorator.